# Solutions to Exercises in Goldrei, Propositional and Predicate Calculus

Tags: logic, reference-request, self-learning

Is a solution manual available for the exercises in Goldrei's logic book? I am interested, in particular, in solutions to his exercises at the end of each chapter.

Comment: I don't think I have ever seen a complete solution manual for Goldrei's book; actually not even for any metalogic textbook. The closest I can think of is Chiswell and Hodges' Mathematical Logic - it has solutions to selected exercises (although as far as I can remember a lot of Goldrei's do as well). I would suggest that you post your answer here and ask people to check it for you, if the solution to the exercise you did is not available.

Comment: @DanielMak I know two textbooks that include solutions to *all* the exercises : $Mathematical$ $Logic$ by R. Cori & D. Lascar (2 volumes) and Smullyan's $A$ $Beginner's$ $Guide$ $to$ $Mathematical$ $Logic$

Comment: @Sam Thanks, I haven't heard of either, but I have only heard high praises of anything Smullyan wrote, I will check out the latter

Comment: @DanielMak thanks very much for this response! I guess this is the way I will end up approaching Goldrei, then. (As a side note, I think some of Smullyan's books do include all of the answers! In addition to the book Sam mentions, I think his book on Diagonalization, for instance, includes all of the solutions.)

Comment: @JosiahOber Another thing I can recommend is to not rely on a single textbook; while Goldrei's book is top of the tier, reading other textbooks can give you alternative perspectives of the same concept, which is always a good thing. (David Makinson taught me that and I've been practicing it since)

You can refer to Peter Smith's excellent TYL for textbook recommendations, I don't think I've ever seen any recommendation from Smith that is subpar
https://www.logicmatters.net/tyl/

Comment: @DanielMak Thanks very much for this bit of advice, Daniel! I am only just now getting back into self-studying math (it's been years), so I'll take any tips I can get. Regarding Peter Smith's recommendations, do you have any thoughts on his advice re books on model theory?

Comment: @JosiahOber I am personally still struggling with Model theory (trying to pass it to graduate) so I don't think I am in a position to comment because...well, I just find the subject in general to be difficult, so by extension I am biased and find every book I've read difficult to follow. My advice is again try to read different books for the same concept to get different perspectives.